# How to repeat a function on every Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have this transform code as an example but basically I have 3 buttons on my page that load different html files. When I click the first button the function in the .ajaxSend works properly. After I click the next button to load a different html file the .ajaxSend function doesn't work but the html file loads fine.

Am i missing something or is there a way to basically set the function so that it resets everytime I load an html file.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $("#content").hide().load(page).fadeIn('500');

  return false;
});

$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
       $('body').css('transform', 'rotate(360deg)');
   },300);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation of 360 degree is the rotation from the original position (0deg). So once it's rotated, it won't do anything else. You need to add the additional rotation yourself. For that, you could store a variable holding the rotation and increment that by 360 each time `ajaxSend` is called.

```
let rotation = 0;
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
       rotation += 360;
       $('body').css('transform', 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when you click the first button, it applies style='transform:rotate(360deg)' on the body.

When you click the second button, it's simply going to leave style='transform:rotate(360deg)' on body, so it's not going to rotate it again. What I would suggest is, in the ajaxSend function first removing the css from body before adding the css style.

I hope i was clear. Let me know if it works.